# Catch an error from command line Python

Tags: python, command

I need to catch an error from command line without print error message on the screen. When this occurs I need to give another command to run.

This is what I do now:

```
hyst_cmd = "si viewhistory ..."
process = subprocess.Popen(hyst_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
hyst = process.stdout.read().splitlines()
```

When I do this for some projects I receive an error message, on the screen.

Sorry for my english!

Comment: Have you tried putting this code in `try-except` block?? that is a good way to catch the exceptions and you can specify another "command" that you want to run in the `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document, the most common exception for Popen in subprocess is **OSError**.

To catch the error, you can simply try the following approach:

```
hyst_cmd = "si viewhistory ..."

try:
    process = subprocess.Popen(hyst_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    hyst = process.stdout.read().splitlines()

except OSError:
    <write_log_file or other action.>
```

For more information, you can check the link below: 
[Subprocess Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#exceptions)